# "move this discussion to chat" not working

Tags: bug, comments, chat

I and the OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394598/close-button-title-bar-disabled-and-cmd-q-menu-quit-not-working#comment52668549_32394598) are unable to move its discussion to chat.

When I try I get:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here? Or can this be fixed?

Cheers.

Comment: The comments are moved to chat now. As to why you  received that error I'm not sure... could have just been a temporary glitch - whatever it is I'd imagine a developer will have to look to see if it's an issue.

Comment: I've tagged this as a bug rather than a discussion, feel free to roll it back if that wasn't your intent.

Comment: I've noticed SE outage (for a couple of minutes) around that time (in Europe). Couldn't that be the reason?

Comment: @TLama Well the servers got moved __again__, so could that be why? When that happened chat also went down

Comment: @Uniforms, who knows. But we have been warned :) [they said](http://stackstatus.net/), *We don’t have an exact schedule as this will be a fluid schedule “as things get done” style, finishing as quickly as we can. There should be no downtime for Q&A, only a brief period of read-only traffic as we migrate databases masters to New York. Other services like API and Careers will have similar behavior.* ***Chat will undergo a brief outage*** *as we flip it over (on the order of minutes).* And I noticed Q&A outage reported on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

Comment: Could've been a simple 'move comments from `x` server to `y` server', but `y` server was being moved and was offline and moving the comments to chat failed..